# No visible @interface for 'FIRInstanceID' declares the selector 'setAPNSToken:type:'

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

after updating Pod library getting above error in appdelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {

    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
    NSString *newToken = [deviceToken description];
    newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", newToken);

}
```

Answer (score 7):

It is deprecated code, you should try with the `FIRMessaging`

You can update your code to look like this

```
// With "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled": NO
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;
}
```

Refer [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an old version of `firebase_messaging` in your `pubspec.yaml`. Make sure you have the [latest version](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging). If this does not help, go to the ios folder (`cd ios/`), then run `pod update`, and then `flutter clean`. Then, run your app again.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solutions:**
Probably it is a problem with latest firebase version (v6). Change firebase version in Podfile.
add below line to Podfile

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~>5.20.2'
```

Then run `pod update`

This help me fixed problem

Comment: pod install instead of pod update