# 'InstanceID' does not contain definition for 'SetApnsToken' after updating Firebase packages

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Xamarin.iOS project I have updated Firebase nuget packages, after completing updates I started getting error on this code

```
//You'll need this method if you set "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled": NO in GoogleService-Info.plist
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    SISConst.PushInfo = new PushNotification();
    SISConst.PushInfo.DeviceID = deviceToken.ToString();
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(deviceToken.ToString(),"dToken");

#if DEBUG
    Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken, Firebase.InstanceID.ApnsTokenType.Sandbox);
#if RELEASE
    Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken, Firebase.InstanceID.ApnsTokenType.Prod);
}
```

Lines below showing error

```
Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken, Firebase.InstanceID.ApnsTokenType.Sandbox);
```

Refer screenshot for more information

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can set ApnsToken like this. Checkout my answer here if that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078653/no-visible-interface-for-firinstanceid-declares-the-selector-setapnstokenty/53079056#53079056

Comment: I am not getting `SetApnsToken`. Don't know under which namespace coming it. I am getting `ApnsTokenType`. Thank you.

Comment: [FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken; this way you can set APNSToken. don't you able to see it?

Comment: Hi, Just now got answer. Xamarin has little different syntax or packages. Thank you for your support. Have a look on my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got answer after struggling few hours

```
if DEBUG
            Firebase.CloudMessaging.Messaging.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken, ApnsTokenType.Sandbox);
endif
if RELEASE
            Firebase.CloudMessaging.Messaging.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken,ApnsTokenType.Production);
endif
```